# Clipping raster to multiple rasters for each parcel using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, polygon, data-driven-pages

I have a raster aerial photo.  I have county wide parcel data.

**I want to clip/screen shot the raster at each individual parcel**.

Think of this application - a post card with an image of your house --here is your house--

I want to have each parcel attribute to contain information + hyperlink of the aerial photo.

Any other solutions welcome, but this is the only method I could think of. Although I am unsure of how to achieve it efficiently.

Using ArcInfo 10.

Comment: What is your eventual use going to be?  Knowing that would help someone provide a more focused solution.

Comment: Yeah.  I want to get an aerial photo for each house in the county.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [ArcGIS Forum Posting](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17492-clip-output-to-graphics-extent-with-arcpy) - it sounds a lot like what you are wanting to do.

I found it by thinking along the lines of a map book with a page for each property and the need to apply a graphic clip or mask to leave just the property image showing.

Your map pages would need to be exported to the format of your choice and those locations written using an ArcPy update cursor into the attribute table.

From @Thad as a comment:

> But it is simpler. Here is the workflow. Use Data Driven Pages, but
>   instead of using a grid use the parcel polygons as the map extents.
>   Then Layer properties - dataframe - clip to current data driven pages
>   extent.

Comment: Seems like a brilliant idea! I would have never thought of it. Gonna play with it and see how it works.

Comment: Ok.  You were right on the money.  But it is simpler.  Here is the workflow.  Use Data Driven Pages, but instead of using a grid use the parcel polygons as the map extents.  Then Layer properties - dataframe - clip to current data driven pages extent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to subset your raster via Image Analysis Window - Clip Tool.

This tool is fine to cut any parts of your image. http://goo.gl/E3ivO